# Having trouble with initializing a variable with two different options of random numbers

Tags: java, string, variables, int

I'm attempting to create a MasterCard number generator (shady, I know, but it's just for class I promise! :) ) The card number has to start with either a number between 51-55 (inclusive) or a number between 222100-272099 (also inclusive). Is there any way to set a variable to be either of these? This is the line of code I wrote, but it returned this error message: "error: bad operand types for binary operator '||' ".

```
int firstNum = randGen.nextInt(5) + 51 || randGen.nextInt(50000) + 222100;
```

This number will end up eventually being a string 16 numbers long that follows the Luhn formula, so if there is an easier way to do this/troubleshoot it, please let me know!

Comment: You can't use `||` that way and I think there isn't a short way to do it. Do you need the same probability for the two cases or for each of the total possibilities?

Comment: Your question is not clear, how the final number should look like? you said *This number will end up eventually being a string 16 numbers long* but the result is 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable to either of those values, but only one at a time. You need to make a choice. You can make the choice in random using the random number generator you already have.

```
if (randGen.nextBoolean())
    firstNum = randGen.nextInt(5) + 51;
else 
    firstNum = randGen.nextInt(50000) + 222100;
```

Answer (score 1):

A clean solution would be to generate an array of the two random numbers and then choose one of them randomly as shown below:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random randGen = new Random();
        int[] nums = new int[2];
        nums[0] = randGen.nextInt(5) + 51;
        nums[1] = randGen.nextInt(50000) + 222100;

        // Assign one of the random numbers to firstNum
        int firstNum = nums[randGen.nextInt(2)];
        System.out.println(firstNum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `||` operator only between boolean expression. Another simple solution with a different distribution would be

```
        int firstNum = randGen.nextInt(50005) + 51;
        if (firstNum > 55){ firstNum += (222100-56);}
```

In this case there would be a roughly similar probabiblity to get 53 or 222111, but a higher probability to get a number between 222100 and 272099 then a number between 51 and 55.